# PRI method in http2 implementation causing issue

Tags: http, go, http2

I am trying to extend a server with **HTTP/2** which already supports **HTTP/1.1** with **TLS v1.2**. I am writing it in **Go** where I define tls config like this -

```
tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
                    Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
                    ServerName:   "mysrvr",
                    NextProtos:   []string{"h2", "http/1.1", "http/1.0"},
                    Time:         time.Now,
                    Rand:         rand.Reader,
            }
```

As is evident, I have used "**h2**" string to set up ALPN handshake.

Now when I make request via curl, I receive this request -

```
$ curl -v https://127.0.0.1:8000 -k --http2
```

When I parse request, it shows a **PRI** method being sent first instead of **GET** -

```
HTTP/2.0
PRI
```

I got some idea on **PRI** method from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#page-78 wherein it says the following -

```
This method is never used by an actual client.
This method will appear to be used when an HTTP/1.1 server or
intermediary attempts to parse an HTTP/2 connection preface.
```

My question now is why was **PRI** request sent, when clearly the server supports **HTTP/2**? Do I need to parse it and respond with empty **SETTINGS** frame in accordance with HTTP/2 spec or should the Go http2 runtime should have taken care of it?

I am using `http.ReadRequest` to parse client requests, but that doesn't seem to be working for **HTTP/2** requests even when I ignore **PRI** requests (as suggested below).

Comment: Why do you write your own HTTP server when the standard library includes an HTTP server that already supports HTTP/2? Reinventing the wheel is usually a bad idea.

Comment: My use case is a bit different. Plus I would want to understand more of Go and http2 through this experiment.

Answer (score 8):

The first message a HTTP/2 client should send is this PRI message. From the [HTTP/2 specification](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#ConnectionHeader):

> In HTTP/2, each endpoint is required to send a connection preface as a final confirmation of the protocol in use and to establish the initial settings for the HTTP/2 connection. The client and server each send a different connection preface.
>
> The client connection preface starts with a sequence of 24 octets, which in hex notation is:
>
> ```
> 0x505249202a20485454502f322e300d0a0d0a534d0d0a0d0a
> ```
>
> That is, the connection preface starts with the string PRI * HTTP/2.0\r\n\r\nSM\r\n\r\n). This sequence MUST be followed by a SETTINGS frame (Section 6.5), which MAY be empty.
>
> ...
>
> **Note**: The client connection preface is selected so that a large proportion of HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/1.0 servers and intermediaries do not attempt to process further frames.

The point of this message is that it is a fake HTTP/1-like message so any server which is not HTTP/2 aware should response with an error.

Any HTTP/2 server should expect this message to be sent, and then should just ignore it, and the carry on speaking HTTP/2.

In fact if this message is NOT sent, then the server should treat this as an error and not continue:

> Clients and servers MUST treat an invalid connection preface as a connection error (Section 5.4.1) of type PROTOCOL_ERROR. A GOAWAY frame (Section 6.8) MAY be omitted in this case, since an invalid preface indicates that the peer is not using HTTP/2.

Comment: So the question remains how should I 'ignore' it? And I am assuming if I read from tcp connection again, I should get the GET request. By the way, I am using Go's http.ReadRequest to parse http requests and I write directly onto the TCP connection.

Comment: I don't know Go that well to be honest, but I would imagine it should handle this transparently and not make it available to you if you have Go with HTTP/2 support. Are you using Go 1.6 or above?

Comment: I am using Go 1.10.2. What is baffling to me is why is PRI even needed for http2 requests when ALPN handshake sets the protocol as "h2".

Comment: Because ALPN is a TLS thing, and technically has nothing to do with HTTP. At a HTTP layer it has no idea which ALPN method was selected (h2 or http/1.1) - though of course the web server will know and could use that knowledge to handle the request appropriately. On the other hand, while this may not technically be needed for the h2 method of HTTP/2 negotiation, it is for all the other h2c methods, and I guess they thought it would be better to be consistent. Also it is possible to offload TLS at edge server and send the decrypted message to a h2c web server so it would be needed for that.

Comment: I can get along with the consistency reasoning. On debugging more, I found that I can read a blob (original req) directly from tcp connection after the connection preface, but http.ReadRequest blocks without throwing any read error.

Comment: Without knowing Go it really sounds to me like http.ReadRequest is expecting HTTP/1.1 formatted messages, otherwise it would just swallow the PRI message and give you the first real message.

Comment: And reading the blob is going to be complicated - the first HTTP/2 Frame that a client should send is a SETTINGS Frame. You should also send your own SETTINGS Frame and acknowledge that the Client sent one. HTTP/2 really is quite a different beast than HTTP/1.1 and building a full HTTP/2 server is quite complicated. If it’s not too much of a shameless plug, Chapter 4 of my book (https://www.manning.com/books/http2-in-action) delves into the binary format and walks you through the messaging sequence, though HPACK Header compression is not covered until Chapter 7.

Comment: Sure. I'll go through it.